# Foreign Keys to Composite Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have a table where `AId` is the primary key and `BId` and `CId` are foreign keys referencing their tables. I need to make the combination of `BId` and `CId` unique.

How would I alter the table to make the combination unique?

Thanks

```
AId    BId   CId   Notes     Date
===    ===   ===   =====     ====
1      200   1     Random    2/2/2005
2      201   2     ETC       2/8/2007
3      202   3     ETC       2/12/2012
```

Comment: Search for "sql server unique index" with various modifiers like "create" or "add". There should be plenty of results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a unique index or a unique constraint.

I generally prefer unique indexes as they are more flexible (can add included columns if desired) and they don't have to be uniquely named in the schema.

Example syntax for a unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX SomeIndex ON YourTable(BId,  CId)
```

The order of `BId,  CId` makes no difference to the uniqueness guarantee but does affect the queries the index can efficiently support (that way round supports looking up by `Bid` or `BId,  CId` but not `CId`)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraint 
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
           BId, CId
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create unique indexes that are not the primary key.  This will force the combination of BId and CId unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_ATable_AltUniqueIndex ON ATable(BId,CId)
```

Or you can create a unique constraint

```
 ALTER TABLE ATable ADD CONSTRAINT uni_ATable UNIQUE (BId,CId)
```

Create a unique constraint appears to create a unique index also.